# Scala - Convert a string to a timestamp

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm working with PostgreSQL and PlayFramework, and I need to convert an `Option[String]` to a `Timestamp` for execute my query.

My `Option[String]` is a date in that format: `2016/07/26`

And the format of the timestamp is: `2016-07-26`

I know I can add  `to_stimetamp(myDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` to my query but I don't want use that (actually I don't know if I will use MySQL or PostgreSQL later an that function doesn't exist in MySQL)

So how can I do ?

Comment: Is the type of timestamp a String as well or a custom class? If the former you could just e.g. `def format(opt: Option[String]): String = {
val str = opt getOrElse "some/default/date"
str.split('/') mkString("-")
}`

Comment: are you asking how to do it in scala?

Comment: Yes i'm askin how can I do in scala, at the end I want that my query work with PostgreSQL and MySQL so I need to convert it "in Scala" before I launch my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import org.joda.time.DateTime
 import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
 import scala.util.Try

 object Test extends App {
   val sourceFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd")
   val targetFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")

   def parse(str: String): Option[DateTime] = {
     Try(DateTime.parse(str, sourceFormat)).toOption
   }

   val input = "2015/07/11"
   val maybeDate = parse(input)
   println(maybeDate.map(_.toString(targetFormat)))
   // Some("2015-07-11")
 }
```

It's also more efficient to use the `parse` method together with a `DateTimeFormat` that was pre-computed, otherwise the format will be validated every single time. If you call `toString`, internally that will also attempt to rebuild a `DateTimeFormat` from a `String` once more, which is inefficient.

Unlike the other answer, I would suggest that you never use `DateTime.parse("2016/07/26")`, e.g. don't pass a `String` argument as there's no internal format cache.

Further more `Option.map` doesn't catch errors that can be thrown by `DateTime.parse`, so if you only use `Option` it will blow up at runtime with an error if the string doesn't parse, instead of properly returning a `None`. Using a `Try` solves that problem.

Comment: It's seems that "toOption" is not a member of org.joda.time.DateTime

Comment: The `toOption` call is on the `Try`, make sure you are copying everything. I've added the top level import for `scala.util.Try` to hopefully clear everything up.

Comment: I try it in my query but it doesn't work, here is my query:
`SQL("""select id from intervalle_date where date_debut={date_debut}""".stripMargin).on(
        'date_debut -> startDateParsed.map(_.toString(targetFormat))).as(scalar[Long].singleOpt)` 

The error is:
[PSQLException : Error: The operator doesn't exist : date = character varying]

Comment: Hi @Clement.Cvl That are looks different and I don't know which SQL library you are using to be honest. Can you paste the resulting SQL string?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an implicit conversion for timestamp literals.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time.Instant

object util {
  implicit class StringTimeConversions(sc: StringContext) {
    def t(args: Any*): Timestamp =
      Timestamp.from(Instant.parse(sc.s(args:_*)))
  }
}

import util._
val time: Timestamp = t"2007-01-01T00:00:00.00Z"
```

Comment: why the `Any*` has a `*`; and can one use it like this: `t("the string values")`

Comment: i understand a bit more regarding to how to use the extension method `t`, after reading the `StringContext` class docString. It has examples of parse json string to json object. but I am still not sure why the `Any*` as the args type.

Comment: note: try not to use java.sql.Timestamp (old legacy type), instead use the new one, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766674/convert-java-time-instant-to-java-sql-timestamp-without-zone-offset

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **joda** DateTime then you can simply call parse method like this:

```
DateTime.parse("2016/07/26")
```

If string is wrapped in Option then you can simply use this:

```
val d = Option("2016/07/26")
d.map(dt => DateTime.parse(d))
```

Or else if you are on java.util.Date then you may use SimpleDateFormat like this:

```
val f = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
f.parse("2016/07/26")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. Define your own format and parse the timestamp.

First the required `imports` :

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
```

The below code will return a `ZonedDateTime` which is a more generic format to work with -

```
        val tsFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(tsFormat)
        // sample date 2021-05-07T00:00:00+00:00
        val startTs = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Timestamp.valueOf and String.replaceAll to fix the slashes. You also need to have add the time (just fix it to midnight, or whatever you want):

```
Timestamp.valueOf("2015/06/08".replaceAll("/", "-") + " 00:00:00")
```