# Convert java.time.Instant to java.sql.Timestamp without Zone offset

Tags: java, date, time, timestamp, java.time.instant

In the application I am developing, I need to convert `java.time.Instant` object to `java.sql.Timestamp`. When I create `Instant` object like:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

I receive something like `2017-03-13T14:28:59.970Z`. And when I try to create `Timestamp` object like this:

```
Timestamp current = Timestamp.from(now);
```

I receive something like `2017-03-13T16:28:59.970Z`. The same result but with an additional 2 hour delay.
Can someone explain why this is happening and provide me with an answer to fix this problem without this delay?

When I created like this:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
Timestamp current = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
```

Everything works well, but I try to avoid conversions. Is there a way to do this by only using `Instant` object?

Comment: Are you sure both of them really show `Z`? Can you provide a [mcve] to demonstrate this without a debugger?

Comment: For now I can't provide you, but I am almost sure that the record in the database would be with applied zone offset. The second example is tested, and the record is as I expected.

Comment: @JonSkeet . Sorry I am wrong, no Z appeared in Timestamp current = Timestamp.from(now);

Comment: Right - and is your local time zone two hours ahead of UTC at the moment? If so, the two values represent the same point in time.

Comment: Yeah, I want 0 offset, as the second example, without conversion (from instant to LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime) if is possible.

Comment: Are you just looking at the `toString()` representation? It's not clear why it matters.

Comment: mmm, I don't think so. You are right that this which eclipse show me is the toString() mthod of the object. I saw the structure of the Timestamp instance and the zone offset value was set to specific value

Comment: You are doing everything correctly. A `Timestamp` doesn’t have a time zone association, but it seems its `toString` method uses your computer’s default time zone.

Comment: On the other hand, I think the result you get from `Timestamp.valueOf(ldt)` differs from what you want. The documentation of the method says: “The provided LocalDateTime is interpreted as the local date-time in the local time zone.” So this does not give you the time in UTC. In other words, it gives you a time that is different from the `Instant,now()` you started out from.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, but during the documentation, LocalDateTime does not hold any timezone information. You can build it using offset from standard UTC of your specific zone. (+2 is mine). My instance of LocalDateTime is build with +0 offset, so the Timestamp copy it and transform it it;s structure. But my qestion is why doen't do it with my Instant object, which represent nano seconds from 1970 in UTC. Does my Instant holds my timezone offset, or Timestamp add it.

Comment: Neither `Instant` nor `Timestamp` *holds* any time zone offset. `Timestamp.toString()` picks up your computer's default time zone and uses it for display, which is what confuses you. So even though rhey hold the same number of milliseconds inUTC, they don't display the same.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, but when I create it like the first example I shared and put it into the database, the offset is still there and the record is with +2 hours offset of the desired. Using the second example the result is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137979/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-aleydin-karaimin).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I changed my computer’s time zone to Europe/Bucharest for an experiment. This is UTC + 2 hours like your time zone.

Now when I copy your code I get a result similar to yours:

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    System.out.println(now); // prints 2017-03-14T06:16:32.621Z
    Timestamp current = Timestamp.from(now);
    System.out.println(current); // 2017-03-14 08:16:32.621
```

Output is given in comments. However, I go on:

```
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    // the following prints: Timestamp in UTC: 14-03-2017 06:16:32
    System.out.println("Timestamp in UTC: " + df.format(current));
```

Now you can see that the `Timestamp` really agrees with the `Instant` we started out from (only the milliseconds are not printed, but I trust they are in there too). So you have done everything correctly and only got confused because when we printed the `Timestamp` we were implicitly calling its `toString` method, and this method in turn grabs the computer’s time zone setting and displays the time in this zone. Only because of this, the displays are different.

The other thing you attempted, using `LocalDateTime`, appears to work, but it really does not give you what you want:

```
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(ldt); // 2017-03-14T06:16:32.819
    current = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
    System.out.println(current); // 2017-03-14 06:16:32.819
    System.out.println("Timestamp in UTC: " + df.format(current)); // 14-03-2017 04:16:32
```

Now when we print the `Timestamp` using our UTC `DateFormat`, we can see that it is 2 hours too early, 04:16:32 UTC when the `Instant` is 06:16:32 UTC. So this method is deceiving, it looks like it’s working, but it doesn’t.

This shows the trouble that lead to the design of the Java 8 date and time classes to replace the old ones. So the real and good solution to your problem would probably be to get yourself a JDBC 4.2 driver that can accept an `Instant` object readily so you can avoid converting to `Timestamp` altogether. I don’t know if that’s available for you just yet, but I’m convinced it will be.

Comment: Detail: A JDBC 4.2 compliant driver *might* use an `Instant`, but is *required* to use an `OffsetDateTime`. To convert: `OffsetDateTime odt = myInstant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;`

Answer (score 58):

## Wrong classes to use

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instnant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
Timestamp current = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
```

Two problems with that code.

Firstly, never mix the modern *java.time* classes (`LocalDateTime` here) with the terrible old legacy date-time classes (`java.sql.Timestamp` here). The *java.time* framework supplants entirely the terrible old classes, as of the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). You need never use `Timestamp` again: As of [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

The other problem, is that the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class cannot, by definition, represent a moment. It purposely lacks a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Use `LocalDateTime` only when you mean a date with time-of-day *everywhere* or *anywhere*, in other words, any/all of many more moments across a range of about 26-27 hours (the current extremes of time zones around the globe).

Do *not* use  [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) when you mean a specific moment, a specific point on the timeline. Instead use:

- [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) (always in UTC)
- [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) (a date with time-of-day and with offset-from-UTC)
- [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) (a date with time-of-day and with a time zone).

> Then I try to create Timestamp object

**Don’t.**

Never use `java.sql.Timestamp`. Replaced by `java.time.Instant`. Read on for more info.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both modern and legacy) and in standard SQL.]

## Current moment

To capture the current moment in UTC use either of these:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

…or…

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

The both represent the very same thing, a moment in UTC.

## Database

Here is some example [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) and the Java code to pass the current moment into the database.

The example uses the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), built in Java.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO event_ ( name_ , when_ ) " + "VALUES ( ? , ? ) ;";
try ( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ; ) {
    String name = "whatever";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC );

    preparedStatement.setString( 1 , name );
    preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , odt );
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Here is a complete example app using that code.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MomentIntoDatabase {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        MomentIntoDatabase app = new MomentIntoDatabase();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:h2:mem:moment_into_db_example_" ) ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE event_ (\n" +
                    "  id_ UUID DEFAULT random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
                    "  name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL ,\n" +
                    "  when_ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL\n" +
                    ") ; ";
            System.out.println( sql );
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO event_ ( name_ , when_ ) " + "VALUES ( ? , ? ) ;";
            try ( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ; ) {
                String name = "whatever";
                OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC );

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , name );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , odt );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }

            // Query all.
            sql = "SELECT * FROM event_ ;";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    UUID id = ( UUID ) rs.getObject( "id_" );  // Cast the `Object` object to UUID if your driver does not support JDBC 4.2 and its ability to pass the expected return type for type-safety.
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    OffsetDateTime odt = rs.getObject( "when_" , OffsetDateTime.class );

                    //Display values
                    System.out.println( "id: " + id + " | name: " + name + " | when: " + odt );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## Parsing string

Regarding a related comment by Melnyk, here is another example based on the example code above. Rather than capturing the current moment, this code parses a string.

The input string lacks any indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So we parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), keeping in mind that this does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

```
String input = "22.11.2018 00:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-11-22T00:00

But we have been informed the string was meant to represent a moment in UTC, but the sender screwed up and failed to include that information (such as a `Z` or `+00:00` on the end to mean UTC). So we can apply an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds to determine an actual moment, a specific point on the timeline. The result as a `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-11-22T00:00Z

The `Z` on the end means UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”. Defined in ISO 8601 standard.

Now that we have a moment in hand, we can send it to the database in a column of SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , odt );
```

When then retrieve that stored value.

```
 OffsetDateTime odt = rs.getObject( "when_" , OffsetDateTime.class );
```

> 2018-11-22T00:00Z

Here is the complete for this example app.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MomentIntoDatabase {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        MomentIntoDatabase app = new MomentIntoDatabase();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:h2:mem:moment_into_db_example_" ) ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE event_ (\n" +
                    "  id_ UUID DEFAULT random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
                    "  name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL ,\n" +
                    "  when_ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL\n" +
                    ") ; ";
            System.out.println( sql );
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO event_ ( name_ , when_ ) " + "VALUES ( ? , ? ) ;";
            try ( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ; ) {
                String name = "whatever";
                String input = "22.11.2018 00:00:00";
                DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss" );
                LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
                System.out.println( "ldt.toString(): " + ldt );
                OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
                System.out.println( "odt.toString(): " + odt );

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , name );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , odt );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }

            // Query all.
            sql = "SELECT * FROM event_ ;";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    UUID id = ( UUID ) rs.getObject( "id_" );  // Cast the `Object` object to UUID if your driver does not support JDBC 4.2 and its ability to pass the expected return type for type-safety.
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    OffsetDateTime odt = rs.getObject( "when_" , OffsetDateTime.class );

                    //Display values
                    System.out.println( "id: " + id + " | name: " + name + " | when: " + odt );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## Converting

If you must interoperate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can convert back-and-forth. Look to new methods `to…`/`from…` added to the old classes.

To get a legacy [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object, call [`Timestamp.from( Instant )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from(java.time.Instant)). To get an `Instant` from our `OffsetDateTime` object seen above, simply call `OffsetDateTime::toInstant`.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from( odt.toInstant() ) ;
```

Going the other direction.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( ts.toInstant() , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

If using the *ThreeTen-Backport* library for Java 6 & 7 projects, look to the [`DateTimeUtils`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) class for the `to…`/`from…` conversion methods.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: @Dogbert_1825027 (A) As for the need to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, good point. Your comment prompted me to add a *Converting* section near the bottom with examples of code going back-and-forth between the legacy and modern classes. (B) As for my insistence on avoiding the legacy classes, I stand by my position. The **legacy date-time classes really are that bad**, flawed in many ways, terribly difficult to work with as can be seen by the profusion of questions here on Stack Overflow. Adding *ThreeTen-Backport* to an old Java 6/7 project is well worth the bother.

Answer (score 3):

Instant always gives time in UTC whereas Timestamp gives time in your local zone.
So if you are not concern about any specific time zone, you can use Instant.
It's also a good practice to save records in UTC, so that your application remains unaffected in case it is deployed in any other timezone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the current timestamp why not use the following function, I have used this in various projects and works perfectly:

```
public static Timestamp getTimeStamp()
{
    // Calendar information
    Calendar calendar       = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.util.Date now      = calendar.getTime();
    Timestamp dbStamp       = new Timestamp(now.getTime());
    return dbStamp;
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println( getTimeStamp() );
```

Output: **2017-03-13 15:01:34.027**

**EDIT**

Using Java 8 LocalDateTime:

```
public static Timestamp getTimeStamp()
{
    return Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now());
}
```

Comment: thank you but I want to use the java 8 way, because of it's immutable classes

Comment: @AleydinKaraimin I added a different way that gives the same output using LocalDateTime. How about this?

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned it in my post that using this way is fine, but, I want to use only instant, and want to learn the reason why this happens. Maybe the creation of timestamp add offset, when accept instant

Answer (score 0):

During saving a record to SQL Server DB I faced with the same problem. I've used  `java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(String s)` to get **Timestamp** in **UTC**:

`import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
....
....
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(UTC);
String dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.format(Instant date);
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime);`

It works for me.

Comment: **Never use `java.sql.Timestamp` class.** It was entirely supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. No need to mix the terrible legacy classes with the modern. `Timestamp` was replaced by `Instant`(always in UTC by definition) or `OffsetDateTime` (set to UTC).

Comment: I use **java.sql.Timestamp class** to store date into DB.

Comment: Timestamp was replaced by `OffsetDateTime` as of JDBC 4.2. Search Stack Overflow. This has been covered many many times already. `myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , Instant.now().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ) ;`

Comment: I have: `String dateStr = "22.11.2018 00:00:00"; OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = date.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC); -> 2018-11-22T00:00Z`  **SQl Server DB** stores offsetDateTime as 2018-11-21 22:00:00.000 instead of 2018-11-22 00:00:00.000

Comment: I added [my own Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53508624/642706) with example code for you to follow. That example uses the H2 Database Engine, though I expect you to see the same results if using Microsoft SQL Server.