# String to ZonedDateTime and timestamp conversion format

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using a SQL Server which has a column with dateTime.
I want to insert the user input String into the DB, for which i try to insert using timestamp.

Following code in Java converts String to ZonedDateTime.

**Case 1:**

```
String ip="2018-05-01T06:47:35.422-05:00";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(ip, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(Timestamp.from(zdt.toInstant()));
```

Output is 2018-05-01 06:47:35.422

**Case 2:**

If String ip="2011-04-07T00:00:00.000-04:00";
Output is 2011-04-06 23:00:00.0

In the second case, why is the date getting changed to previous day and the time is considering offset?

Comment: So, what is your question here?

Comment: why is the date getting changed to previous day and the time is considering offset only in case 2?

Comment: Related: [Java - Convert java.time.Instant to java.sql.Timestamp without Zone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766674/java-convert-java-time-instant-to-java-sql-timestamp-without-zone-offset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code I tried.  Notice that since I am in -7:00 timezone, it subtracts an additional 2 hours from the -5:00 specified in the time string.  Since you are not seeing an offset, I presume you are in the -5:00 timezone.  That is why in your 2nd case (-4:00 string), it must subtract an additional 1 hour, putting it in the day before.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ip="2018-05-01T06:47:35.422-05:00";
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(ip, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);

    // my timezone is: -7:00
    System.out.println(zdt.toInstant());                 // 2018-05-01T11:47:35.422Z
    System.out.println(Timestamp.from(zdt.toInstant())); // 2018-05-01 04:47:35.422
}
```